# SMARTS string matching an aldehyde or a ketone where the target alpha carbon is less substituted than the other carbon

Tags: cheminformatics

I need a SMARTS string that matches the following critereon:

- It makes an aldehyde or a ketone only
- The target carbon is an alpha carbon
- The other alpha carbon must be more substituted (or be an aldehyde)
- The target carbon must not be more substited than a secondary carbon

I came up with the following string:

```
[C;X4;$([H3,H2;$(CC(=O)[H])]),$([H3;$(CC(=O)C)]),$([H2;$(CC(=O)[C;!H3])])]
```

Translated, this is saying, the target carbon:

- Has four bonds
- Lives in any one of the following environments:

  - Is has two or three hydrogens and is on an aldehyde
  - Has three hydrogens and is on a ketone
  - Has two hydrogens and is on a ketone where the other alpha carbon does not have three hydrogens

But that seems very long for what seems like a simple critereon.

Any suggestions? Are there any cool SMARTS tips I'm missing?

Thanks,

Comment: You don't say whether the target carbon must be aliphatic, but your SMARTS string assumes that it does.  (You are using `C` instead of `[#6]` to specify carbon atoms.).  I suppose "not more substituted than a secondary carbon" implies that it does?

Comment: Also, I don't think it seems long.  It is _not_ a simple criterion.  It's fairly complicated, and if I came up with that SMARTS pattern, I'd feel pretty proud of myself.

Comment: You might want to check out [SMARTS viewer](https://smartsview.zbh.uni-hamburg.de/smartsview/f0e925b1947a9bec958a64c5d862be2584197e19b152119577fdf0d01f55) which can help with visualizing and debugging SMARTS. I also usually try the patterns on a few data sets and make sure it looks like a good match. (BTW, it's not *that* long for what you describe.)